# Computing the Sample Size for the sum of Bernoulli RVs with different probabilites times a constant

Tags: p-value, weighted-sampling

I have the following statistic for which I need to figure out a sample size:

$$S= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(c_i+\sum_{j=1}^{100} b_{ij}X_i\right)$$

where $c_i$ and $b_{ij}$ are constants and $X_i$ is Bernoulli with parameter $p_i$.

I need to be able to estimate the precision of this statistic versus the underlying result in the population.

The $X_i$'s are probably not completely independent, i.e. $X_1$ may be correlated to $X_{32}$ but $X_{57}$ is independent of the other $X_i$'s or combinations of $X_i$'s. Since I think it would be almost impossible to compute $n$ under these circumstances, can I somehow estimate the error introduced by assuming the $X_i$'s are independent?

I am hoping there is some way to exploit the form of the statistic (it is an average), but in researching the sum of Bernoulli's with different $p$'s, it's going to be pretty tough.  It could be that Monte Carlo methods are the only way, but I wanted to be ask before I did that.

Comment: Consider simplifying the question by algebraically rewriting it.  Set $$\gamma=\sum_i c_i/n$$ and $$\omega_i=\sum_j b_{ij}/n$$ so that $$S=\gamma+\sum_i\omega_i X_i.$$ At this point the application of standard rules of expectation and variance will directly answer your question.

Comment: Thank you.  I never thought to break it up into component parts!  In the case of independent X_i's we get a straight forward computation of the mean and variance.  For those X_i's that are correlated, I think we just have covariance terms in the variance.  I can compute the covariances.  I assume I can still use standard techniques in this situation, but wanted to double check.  I'm not a real statistician, so I greatly appreciate the help here.

Comment: You are correct on all counts.  Fairly exact calculations of the entire distribution of $S$ are possible when the $X_i$ are independent (using either the FFT or a dynamic program).